# Почему слово "аромамасла" пишется через А?

Tags: орфография

Слово "аромамасла" - сложное, а соединительная гласная, как известно, О. Тогда почему же "аромамасла" пишется через А?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аромамасла (ароматические масла) - это не сложное, а сложносокращенное слово, для сравнения: спецкор, кожзаменитель, спортзал,  вещмешок, капремонт.

Его особенность состоит в том, что усеченная часть включает гласную, что нехарактерно для такого способа образования.

В то же время форма "ароммасла" неудобна ни для для зрительного, ни для слухового восприятия.